# Quartz .net does not work when I inject dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, quartz.net

I am using Quartz .net v2.3.3.0 and Castle Windsor v3.3.0.0.

I have a job which is dependent on a Service

```
public class DemoJob : IJob
    {
          private readonly IService _Service;

          public DemoJob(IService Service)
        {
            _Service = Service;
        }
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            _Service.CallRepoMethod();
        }
    }
```

This is the service class which is in different project

```
public class Service: IService
{

    public void CallRepoMethod()
    {
       Repo();
    }
}
```

Everything  works fine till now.

But as soon as I inject dependency in service class the job is not executed.

```
public class Service: IService
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        Service(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
        public void CallRepoMethod()
        {
            _repository.Repo();
        }
    }
```

IRepository is implemented by a simple Repository class with a single method.
Repository class is in different project and  IService,Service and IRepository are in same project.

I don't get any error message but the job does not get executed. If i remove dependency from the Service class then everything works fine and jobs execute.

Here is how I have registered the dependencies

```
 internal class CastleWindsorContainer : IContainer
    {
        public static WindsorContainer Container { get; private set; }

        public CastleWindsorContainer()
        {
            Container = new WindsorContainer();
        }

        public void Register()
        {

            Container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<Repository>().LifestyleTransient());

        public Object Resolve(Type controllerType)
        {
            return Container.Resolve(controllerType);
        }

        public void Release(IController controller)
        {
            Container.Release(controller);
        }


        public void RegisterJobs(IJobFactory jobFactory)
        {
            Container.Register(Component.For<IJobFactory>().Instance(jobFactory).LifestyleTransient());
            Container.Register(Component.For<IQuartzInitializer>().ImplementedBy<JobsConfig>().LifestyleTransient());
            Container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<Service>().LifestyleTransient());
            Container.Register(Component.For<DemoJob>().ImplementedBy<DemoJob>().LifestyleTransient()

            );
            Container.Resolve<IQuartzInitializer>().RegisterJobs();
        }

    }
```

code in Global.asax

```
 var container = new CastleWindsorContainer();

            IJobFactory jobFactory = new WindsorJobFactory(container);

            container.Register();
            container.RegisterJobs(jobFactory);
```

I am not able to figure out what's wrong. I searched for the solution and found many links but it didn't help because all of them show only one level of dependency. What if the dependent class is dependent on another class?

You can find my demo project here:[DemoProject](http://github.com/MieChul/QuartzWindsor)

Some links I checked

[Quartz .net Windsor Facility](http://bugsquash.blogspot.in/2009/03/windsor-facility-for-quartznet.html)

Thank You

Comment: With the Windsor facility it works with any level of dependency nesting. Can you post your full code to a github repo?

Comment: Hi Mauricio ,
Thank You for the response. Yes, you can find my demo project here HTTPS://github.com/MieChul/QuartzWindsor.git.
Once again thanks for helping

Comment: @MauricioScheffer did you get a chance to go throug my project?

Comment: You're not supposed to create a new scheduler factory in each request, use the one you initialise at app startup. Also you're not using the Windsor facility.